# Magento 2.3.5: Quote in Session

Tags: magento2, cache

I just upgraded to Magento 2.3.5. I'm having an issue where I can't force magento 2 to read the quote from database. It stores the cart in the variable "mage-cache-storage" and reads it from there.

Any help on how to make Magento always read the active quote from the database?

This issue only appeared after I uppdated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some days of trying to understand what happened I gave up and just went for a workaround solution. Here is how I did it, hope it saves someone from days of dispear :) !

Create a mixin for the customer-data.js in the directory **vendor\module\view\frontend\web\js\customer-data.js** as follows:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/section-config',
    'mage/url',
    'mage/storage',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, _, ko, sectionConfig, url) {

    'use strict';

    return function (target) {

        var options = {},
        storage,
        storageInvalidation,
        invalidateCacheBySessionTimeOut,
        invalidateCacheByCloseCookieSession,
        dataProvider,
        buffer,
        customerData;

        url.setBaseUrl(window.BASE_URL);
        options.sectionLoadUrl = url.build('customer/section/load');

        //TODO: remove global change, in this case made for initNamespaceStorage
        $.cookieStorage.setConf({
            path: '/',
            expires: 1
        });

        storage = $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage').localStorage;
        storageInvalidation = $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation').localStorage;

        var getExpiredSectionNames = target.getExpiredSectionNames;
        target.getExpiredSectionNames = function () {
            var expiredSectionNames = ['cart'],
                cookieSectionTimestamps = $.cookieStorage.get('section_data_ids') || {},
                sectionLifetime = options.expirableSectionLifetime * 60,
                currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                sectionData;

            // process sections that can expire due to lifetime constraints
            _.each(options.expirableSectionNames, function (sectionName) {
                sectionData = storage.get(sectionName);

                if (typeof sectionData === 'object' && sectionData['data_id'] + sectionLifetime <= currentTimestamp) {
                    expiredSectionNames.push(sectionName);
                }
            });

            // process sections that can expire due to storage information inconsistency
            _.each(cookieSectionTimestamps, function (cookieSectionTimestamp, sectionName) {
                sectionData = storage.get(sectionName);

                if (typeof sectionData === 'undefined' ||
                    typeof sectionData === 'object' &&
                    cookieSectionTimestamp != sectionData['data_id'] //eslint-disable-line
                ) {
                    expiredSectionNames.push(sectionName);
                }
            });

            return _.uniq(expiredSectionNames);
        };
        return target;
    };
    });
```

This will override the core getExpiredSectionNames , as you can see from the code above, what I'm saying is that the cart is always expired in the cookie, forcing magento to read it from the database (it will use the getQuote from the /Model/Session in the Checkout module.

You will also need to declare the mixin on the requirejs-config.js in the directory (**vendor\module\view\frontend\web\customer-data.js**) as follows:

If you don't have this file in your module, just create it and paste the following code.

```
var config = {
      config: {
        mixins: {
          'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data': {
            'vendor_module/js/customer-data': true        
          },
        }
      }
  };
```